# How to check whether a string is equal to "+" in Java

Tags: java, string, comparison

```
String value = "+";
if (value.contains("\\+"))
{
    value = value.replaceAll("\\+", " ");
}
```

The if clause returns false. Why is it? What method should I use in the if clause for it to return true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... have you ever tried just: "+".equals(value) ? it seems to me you are overthinking this a lot

Comment: Do you want to check if a String is equal to + or if it contains the + symbol?

Comment: `contains` takes a literal string, not a regex! Drop the `\\ `.

Comment: And use replace(), not replaceAll. You don't need regexes here.

Comment: Have you consider just replacing all occurrences without first checking?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, combination of yours and Stultuske's answers solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
value.equals("+")
```

Comment: Throws an exception.. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

Comment: @Amy don't use regex.

Comment: @rcs it's better to call equals on the "+" literal, compared to on the value variable. It avoids risking a NullPointerException

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS rcs changed his answer, he had the contains method there first

Comment: @Stultuske That doesn't matter: `contains` doesn't use regex either.

Comment: @khelwood no, it's the replaceAll she calls after it. but OHGODSPIDERS was commenting on the equals, while that wasn't the reply amy replied on, might keep her confused

Answer (score 0):

don't use `value.equals("+")` as it can gives `nullpointer exception` you can use like `"+".equals(value)` it will works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `\\` while checking for the presence of + in the value using String.contains(). It needs char sequence to search for and not regex. However, you need to pass a regex as the 1st argument of the String.replaceAll() method:

```
String value = "+";
if (value.contains("+"))
{
    value = value.replaceAll("\\+", " ");
}
```

For your case, you can use String.replace() as it accepts String literals.

```
value = value.replace("+", " ");
```

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)